# Strip lines out of list with awk

Tags: awk

I have two lists:

FileList.txt

```
some_data/AaBbCcD (some_data).csv
some_data/EeFfGg (some_data).csv
some_data/HhIiJj (some_data).csv
some_data/KkLlMm (some_data).csv
```

ExcludeList.txt

```
EeFfGg
HhIiJj
```

Now I want to strip ExcludeList.txt out of FileList.txt.
What I currently do is:

```
cat ExcludeList.txt | while IFS=$'\n' read line; do
    awk -vLine="${line}" '!index($0,Line)' FileList.txt >${tmpfile} && mv ${tmpfile} FileList.txt 
done
```

Result

```
some_data/AaBbCcD (some_data).csv
some_data/KkLlMm (some_data).csv
```

This works, but I know this can be done all with awk. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: can you confirm you want exact word matches; for example, `EeFfGg` should *not* match on `EeFfGgHh`, right?

Comment: The right answer will depend on what values `some_data` can take. If you [edit] your question to replace every `some_data` with truly representative values then we can help you.

Answer (score 4):

With your shown samples only, please try following. Written and tested in GNU `awk`, should work in any `awk`. Passing both the Input_file(s) to `awk` program and while reading first file creating an array and while reading 2nd one just checking if 2nd field from 2nd file is NOT present in array then print that line.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  arr[$0]
  next
}
!($2 in arr)
' exclude.txt FS="[/ ]" FileList.txt
```

Comment: This works well for my given example thanks! It does not work on my actual files (I assume because it's not always the second column that needs to match?) grep actually works fine for my purposes.

Comment: @mrchrister, let me add one more solution with `awk` now.

Comment: @mrchrister it would help if the question could be updated with examples from the actual file, especially examples showing the match occurring in different positions within the line

Comment: Thanks, mark and ravinder. This is my first question I ever asked on stackoverflow and you're both amazing with providing me working solutions. grep seems to be the better tool for this job and your answer works well, mark.

Comment: While each will work for your posted example, which solution, if any, will work for other input values depends on the possible values of `some_data` in your example.

Answer (score 2):

Assumptions:

- exact word match is desired (eg, `EeFfGg` does not match on `EeFfGgHh`)
- match can occur anywhere on the line

Setup:

```
$ cat FileList.txt
some_data/AaBbCcD (some_data).csv         # keep
some_data/EeFfGg (some_data).csv          # discard
some_data/EeFfGgHh (some_data).csv        # keep
some_data/abcdefgh (EeFfGg).csv           # discard
some_data/HhIiJj (some_data).csv          # discard
some_data/KkLlMm (some_data).csv          # keep
```

One `grep` approach:

```
$ grep -vwf ExcludeList.txt FileList.txt
some_data/AaBbCcD (some_data).csv
some_data/EeFfGgHh (some_data).csv
some_data/KkLlMm (some_data).csv
```